# Why context.Done() is never being called in the select statement in context with timeout

Tags: go, google-cloud-pubsub

This is my code where I am trying to read messages from  google pub sub

```
func (p *PubSubSource) Read(_ context.Context, readRequest sourcesdk.ReadRequest, messageCh chan<- sourcesdk.Message) {
    if len(p.messages) > 0 {
        return
    }
    log.Println("Request timeout", readRequest.TimeOut())
    ctx, cancelFunc := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), readRequest.TimeOut())
    defer cancelFunc()
    cctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)
    receiveMesg := make(chan *pubsub.Message)
    p.subscription.ReceiveSettings.MaxOutstandingMessages = int(readRequest.Count())
    go p.subscription.Receive(cctx, func(_ context.Context, msg *pubsub.Message) {
        fmt.Printf("Got message------------------: %s\n", string(msg.Data))
        receiveMesg <- msg

    })
    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            log.Println("Timeout done ------------************************")
            cancel()
            return

        case msg := <-receiveMesg:
            log.Println("Executing Loop--------")

            p.lock.Lock()
            messageCh <- sourcesdk.NewMessage(
                msg.Data,
                sourcesdk.NewOffset([]byte(msg.ID), "0"),
                msg.PublishTime,
            )
            p.messages[msg.ID] = msg
            p.lock.Unlock()

        default:
            continue

        }

    }
}
```

The problem is  `case <-ctx.Done()`: never gets executed ,why ?. I want to exit the parent function when the timeout is over ,but `ctx.Done()` never gets called , am I doing this right ,any better way to achieve it

Comment: You have a busy loop! Do not do that! Remove the `default` case, the code will do the same.

Comment: But dont you think my select will block ?? only after first iteration @icza

Comment: Yes it will, and again, no difference. You don't change anything (e.g. `ctx` or `receiveMesg` variables) that would matter (that would require reevaluating them). Blocking will consume 0 CPU, a busy loop will consume 100% CPU core.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `cctx` to `p.subscription.Receive`, not `ctx`. Parent context will not be cancelled when child context is cancelled.

You have to check whether `cctx` is cancelled.

```
case <-cctx.Done():
    log.Println("Timeout done ------------************************")
    cancel()
    return
```